# Codeblocks debug preprocessor

Tags: c++, codeblocks, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a C++ Program with Codeblocks and for debugging-purposes I need to know if the Building-Target of Codeblocks is set to "DEBUG" or to "RELEASE".

I already tried this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Debug-Message");
#endif
```

and this

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    printf("Debug-Message");
#endif
```

But none of this words are defined.
Do I have to define DEBUG on my own and change it, everytime I change the Building-Target, or is there a word I don't know?

Comment: Don't forget to end your debug format strings with `\n`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I have to define DEBUG on my own and change it, everytime I change
>   the Building-Target, or is there a word I don't know?

I don't know what, if anything is set by default by Code::Blocks. But, if you define your own #defines

```
Project->Build options...->[Debug|Release]->#defines
```

you don't have to change them as you switch between build targets (DEBUG or RELEASE). It lets you define  values that are specific to the Debug build, as well as values that are specific to the Release build.

To avoid having to manually enter it each time for each new project you can make a small project with just your Debug/Release #defines and save that as a **project template** and then create new projects from that project template.

Comment: CodeBlocks really should define these since its Debug/Release aware. And it should change `assert`'s behavior from the `abort` to a `trap` when under a Debug configuration. It makes absolutely no sense to `abort` a program while under the debugger. I am amazed at how many people don't use `assert`s because of dumb committee decisions.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way, as suggested by [assert(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/assert) man page and habits (with `<assert.h>` in C or `<cassert>` in C++), is to define `NDEBUG` at the command line (e.g. to compile with `gcc -Wall -DNDEBUG`) for non-debug compilation. In your `Makefile` you could `CPPFLAGS += -DNDEBUG` in release mode (and compile with `g++ -Wall -g` in debug mode).

My own habit might be to have something like

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define dbgprintf(Fmt,...) do{fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d:" Fmt "\n", \
                               __FILE__, __LINE__, \ 
                              ##__VA_ARGS__);}while(0)
#else
#define dbgprintf(Fmt,...) do{}while(0)
#endif
```

in a common header file, and to use `dbgprintf("i=%d", i)` elsewhere in the code. 
Notice that I use constant string catenation on the `Fmt` macro argument, that I append a constant newline to it, and that my debugging output contains the source file name and line number (you might also use `__func__`  if you like). In pure C++ code, I might instead have

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define DBGOUT(Out) do{std::out << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ \
                       << " " << Out << std::endl;}while(0)
#else
#define DBGOUT(Out) do{}while(0)
#endif
```

and use `DBGOUT("i=" << i)` with the advantage of using specific definitions of `operator <<` for my types.